# VBA RegExp causes Compile error while vbscript.regexp works

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I was writing a script for VBA, for Outlook 2013, that uses regular expressions and every example I find seems to use `Set regex = New RegExp` to create a *RegExp object*. When I tried this I got **Compile error: User-defined type not defined**.

I managed to get regular expressions to work using `Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")`.

Any reason why the first options is not working?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Probably only missing some dependencies, meaning some references should be added.

Go to `Tools -> References ->` Find & check the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions" (1.0 or 5.5 both work for me).

Comment: Be careful that References menu entry is grayed out in debugging mode.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was already successfully answered, I just wanted to add a solution that worked for me.

`Tools -> References - > "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"` 
 was already activated.

`Set regex = New RegExp` caused a compile error.

`Set regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp` works.