# regex: match everything, but not a certain string including white sapce (regular expression, inspite of, anything but, VBA visual basic)

Tags: vba, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, lookbehind

Folks, there are already billions of questions on "*regex: match everything, but not ...*", but non seems to fit my simple question.

A simple string: "`1 Rome, 2 London, 3 Wembley Stadium`" and I want to match just "1 `Rome,` 2 `London,` 3 `Wembley Stadium`", in order to extract only the names but not the ranks ("`Rome, London, Wembley Stadium`").

Using a regex tester (https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html), I can simply match the opposite by:

`([0-9]+\s*)` and it gives me:

"`1` Rome, `2` London, `3` Wembley Stadium".

But how to reverse it? I tried something like:

`[^0-9 |;]+[^0-9 |;]`, but it also excludes white spaces that I want to maintain (e.g. after the comma and in between Wembley and Stadium, "1 `Rome,` 2 `London,` 3 `Wembley` `Stadium`"). I guess the "`0-9` " needs be determined somehow as **one continuous** string. I tried various brackets, quotation marks, `\s*`, but nothing jet.

**Note: I'm working in a visual basic environment and not allowing lookbehinds!**

Comment: Try `\d+\s*(.*?)(?:,|$)` and get the values from `match.Submatches(0)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ8Wvi/1).

Comment: If your string is really that simple, you can also use `Split` function to get the array like `Split(simpleStr,",")` then use `Right` with Instr to check for the first white space in each item.

Comment: Or, `\d+\s*(.*?)(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ8Wvi/2).

Comment: ````\d+\s*(.*?)(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)```` matches everything but "````, ````", but I need to match everything, but "````1 ````", "````2 ````", ...  (be aware of the white space behind the numbers)

Comment: No, `\d+\s*(.*?)(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)`  ***captures*** what you need in Group 1. It does not matter what it *matches*.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around. It does not so in: https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html#js. Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\d+\s*(.*?)(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ8Wvi/2), get the values from `match.Submatches(0)`. *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `,`, zero or more whitespaces, one or more digits and then a whitespace OR end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Here is a demo of how to get all matches:

```vb
Sub TestRegEx()
    Dim matches As Object, match As Object
    Dim str As String

    str = "1 Rome, 2 London, 3 Wembley Stadium"
    
    Set regex = New regExp
    regex.Pattern = "\d+\s*(.*?)(?=,\s*\d+\s|$)"
    regex.Global = True

    Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
    
    For Each match In matches
        Debug.Print match.subMatches(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ Wiktor, I know it is frustrating to discuss with people that have no clue of what they are talking about, but I cannot reproduce it. 1. I tried the regex in: https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html#js, but it includes the numbers. 2. I tried to run your macro in Excel, but get a "Compile error: User defined type not defined" and 3. I tried the regex within a VBA function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349611/vba-regex-extract-multiple-strings-between-strings-within-excel-cell-with-custo) and it includes the numbers as indicated by:  https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html#js.

Comment: @MsGISRocker 1) If you do not know how to use the regex from online regex testers, do not use them, rely on what experts advise (really, a [lot of people do not understand how to use online regex testers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39636124/3832970)). 2) Try googling these errors, [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139938/vba-regexp-causes-compile-error-while-vbscript-regexp-works), 3) Why did you try to use the code that is not meant to be used with **my** regex? Use ***my code*** after referencing the right library.

Comment: Ok, I got your script running and yes, it actually does what I asked for. However, it does so only within your script, but not in my function that I would like it to work in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349611/vba-regex-extract-multiple-strings-between-strings-within-excel-cell-with-custo). Is there any more generally applicable solution? BTW, I owe u a coffee!

Comment: @MsGISRocker At Stackoverflow, we can only answer what was asked. If you post your code, I can try to accommodate the solution to fit your code. Without that, I can only suggest what I have.

Comment: Did so! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500504/regex-match-everything-but-not-a-certain-multiletter-string-within-vba-excel-f)